# How does Django make tables relating to user,auth,group,session and so on with very first migration?

Tags: python, django

How does Django framework make initial tables?

If you make Django project and run migrate, it makes tables like below. Even thought you didn't make any apps in project or didn't write any code in models.py for each app.

```
auth_group  
auth_group_permissions
auth_permission     
auth_user       
auth_user_groups        
auth_user_user_permissions      
django_admin_log        
django_content_type     
django_migrations       
django_session
```

I understood what ORM, MTV, migrations are. I want to figure out what in Django made those initial tables.

Addition Question:

I understand that I can control default permissions or custom permission in Meta class. If I don't set any, it makes three default permissions (add,change,delete).

When I migrate as I told you above, I can check those in a table named 'auth_permission'. There are records which is made initially

```
1;"Can add log entry";1;"add_logentry"
2;"Can change log entry";1;"change_logentry"
3;"Can delete log entry";1;"delete_logentry"
4;"Can add permission";2;"add_permission"
5;"Can change permission";2;"change_permission"
6;"Can delete permission";2;"delete_permission"
7;"Can add user";3;"add_user"
8;"Can change user";3;"change_user"
9;"Can delete user";3;"delete_user"
10;"Can add group";4;"add_group"
11;"Can change group";4;"change_group"
12;"Can delete group";4;"delete_group"
13;"Can add content type";5;"add_contenttype"
14;"Can change content type";5;"change_contenttype"
15;"Can delete content type";5;"delete_contenttype"
16;"Can add session";6;"add_session"
17;"Can change session";6;"change_session"
18;"Can delete session";6;"delete_session"
```

How can I manipulate those? E.g. What if I want to change the code names or what if I don't want to make default permissions (add,change,delete)?

Comment: There are apps included by default in each project. See `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! I could find what you mentioned in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py. I understood that If I make new app with command 'python manage.py startapp name', I should add name in INSTALLED_APPS list. How can i find codes for django.contrib.admin in INSTALLED_APPS and how it makes default tables?

Comment: Please move additional questions into a seperate question. And no problem!

Comment: Can you explain how can I find codes for those in INSTALLED_APPS and how it makes default tables?

'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

Comment: The tables are created because of the models included in the aforementioned modules. Searching through the folders where Django was installed will allow you to find the code.

Comment: I thought my first question and second question(which I put label as 'additional question') are connected to each other. Because I wanted to know how Django framework make initial tables and records.

Comment: They should really be seperate. That is the way it goes on SO.

Comment: Thanks. I found codes in where I installed Django. I will read those codes. Thanks again!

Comment: As a note, you can change the permissions for individual instances of the models in the admin site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are apps that are included in the project by default. You can see this is the `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py` file of your project. `auth_group` is a table from `django.contrib.auth`.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out!

Comment: I checked models.py in django/contrib/auth, admin, sessions, messages. there are five tables relating to auth. 
auth_group
auth_group_permissions auth_permission
auth_user
auth_user_groups
auth_user_user_permissions

Comment: I expected that there would be five classes in models.py. I could find class named 'Permission' and class named 'Group' in models.py under auth folder. I understood that auth_group table and auth_permission table is made with those classes. but what about other three tables??? Which part should i look into to understand why those three tables made?(auth_user_user_permission, auth_group_permission, auth_user_group?)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm afraid. You might be able to get some help if you ask another question.

Comment: Okay I will open new question:) Thanks for helping me

Comment: I opened new question and I got answer for it.
[click this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39630862/6568309)